# When did the expression "Supreme Personality of Godhead" start getting used to translate Hindu texts?

Tags: translation

Hindu Texts started getting translated into English and other Western languages at least far back as the late eighteenth century.  As far as I know, the expression "Supreme Personality of Godhead" started getting used from the 1970s on.

Are there any known instances before that?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it comes from ISKCON, specifically Prabhupada to make it easier to understand for a Western audience with a Christian background.

Comment: i think even now, mostly it's found in ISKCON translations..